# Find entity_id & attribute_id of an attribute

Tags: attributes, database

We need to convert a dropdown attribute to multiselect

I found a way here :

If attribute_code : age ,
entity_type_id = 10 ,
store_id = 1

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET
entity_type_id = '10',
attribute_model = NULL,
backend_model = 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
backend_type = 'varchar',
backend_table = NULL,
frontend_model = NULL,
frontend_input = 'multiselect',
frontend_class = NULL
WHERE attribute_id = 'age';
```

Next, copy the attribute values from the old table to the new:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar ( 10, attribute_id, 1, entity_id, value)
SELECT entity_type_id, attribute_id, 1, entity_id, value
FROM catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE attribute_id = age;
```

Finally,  remove the old values or they will conflict with the new setup (the old values will load, but Magento will save new values to the varchar table):

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE entity_type_id = 10 and attribute_id = age;
```

**Credits :**

http://swarminglabs.com/how-to-change-a-product-dropdown-attribute-to-a-multi-select/

but here i want to know how to find "attribute_id and entity_id" for an attribute. so i can replace those values in above queries

Comment: by `entity_id` you mean `entity_type_id`, right?

Comment: Thanks for reply to my post. in database table i saw "entity_type_id" = "10 for that attribute. http://prntscr.com/9sxn7a but i dont know what is entity_id , is both are same ?

Comment: entity_id is the id of the products you want to change. I don't think you need those because you need to change the values for all the products that have that attribute. I think entity_type_id is the one you need. Check my answer and see if it works. Backup your db first though.

Comment: i got attribute_id as "1020" , now in question  in 2nd query , there is "entity_id" text, is i have to remove that?

Comment: can you please update my 2nd query in question

Comment: just replace 10 with what you get from my first query and `age` with what you get from the second query.

Comment: I ran this query, mostly its working..... INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar ( entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT 10, 1020, 1, entity_id, value
FROM catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE attribute_id = 1020;

Comment: Thanks a lot boss.... you are king of magento..............

Comment: for another attribute id , i am getting this error : #1062 - Duplicate entry '6377-1021-1' for key 'UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID'  after i ran the 2nd query, can you please help.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9sy67m please check here

Comment: you can use `nsert ... ON duplicate key update` instead of insert and that will override the values that already exist. Check online how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the `entity_type id` like this.

```
SELECT 
    entity_type_id 
FROM 
    eav_entity_type
WHERE
    entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
```

and the attribute id like this

```
SELECT 
    attribute_id
FROM 
    eav_attribute
WHERE 
    attribute_code = 'age' AND
    entity_type_id = (SELECT 
                          entity_type_id 
                      FROM 
                          eav_entity_type
                      WHERE
                          entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
                      )
```

or simply

```
SELECT 
    attribute_id
FROM 
    eav_attribute
WHERE 
    attribute_code = 'age' AND
    entity_type_id = THE RESULT FROM THE FIRST QUERY
```