# update the database query with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: database

i am following this link :

[Find entity_id & attribute_id of an attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98373/find-entity-id-attribute-id-of-an-attribute?noredirect=1#comment132450_98373)

I used this sql query :

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar ( entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) 
SELECT 10, 1021, 1, entity_id, value
FROM catalog_product_entity_int
WHERE attribute_id = 1021;
```

but i got error in the image :[image]

**@Marius** suggested to use "**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**" . I have no idea about this. when i googled it, i got some solution, but that did't worked.

please give me the updated query using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow script run on magento root folder

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class AR
{
    public function index()
    {
        $writeAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $resultAll = $readAdapter->fetchAll('SELECT `entity_type_id`,`attribute_id` ,`store_id`, `entity_id`, `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id` =1021');
        foreach($resultAll as $result) {
             $writeAdapter->query('DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`attribute_id` =1021;');
            $query = "INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '".$result['entity_type_id']."', '".$result['attribute_id']."', '".$result['store_id']."', '".$result['entity_id']."', '".$result['value']."');";
         $writeAdapter->query($query);
        }

        echo 'Attribute values are updated.';  


    }

}

$obj = new AR();
$obj->index();
?>
```

Comment: but i got this error : http://prntscr.com/9t8weo

Comment: can you share error?

Comment: Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '213-1021-0' for key 'UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID'' in /var/www/html/vikas/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:

Comment: updated ans pls check now..

Comment: it showing blank page, is i have to wait for some more time ?

Comment: yes it blank page

Comment: Pls check your database table "catalog_product_entity_varchar"

Comment: okay, i got the tabel, what i need to chec\k here....

Comment: Search attribute_id = 1021 in this table

Comment: also i have updated ans pls check again

Comment: i can not able to get that attribute id in database, is i have to do any changes in database table ?

Comment: i checked in backend, it worked fine. if any other problem i will let you know...